# Relying on super class to throw exception

Tags: java, inheritance

I am extending list in java, but I am not sure of how to deal with exceptions.

```
class InfiniteList extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    InfiniteList(int size) {
        super(size);
     //   if (size < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The size should not be less than zero.");
        add(size);
    }
```

Here, I know that as of now, ArrayList constructor throws an exception, if size is negative.
My implementation of subclass wants exactly the same behavior.
So far world is good.

Now later someone comes and changes ArrayList to accept the negative size and my `InfiniteList` fails.
So my solution is to add / duplicate exception handling logic in `InfiniteList`. However this comes with issue of code duplication. So I have two options.

1. Trust the super class ?
2. Duplicate code ?

What is the common / best practices etc to do here, given that `Composition` is not an option.

Comment: You're ruling out the best solution: composition. Read http://books.google.fr/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=prefer+composition+over+inheritance+bloch&source=bl&ots=yYLiIgq4P2&sig=c-tj3a5eHxArxBKqbUI69LSdudE&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=-doHU4SfD4XNygOj3oLoCQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=prefer%20composition%20over%20inheritance%20bloch&f=false

Comment: Maybe you can use a wrapper around ArrayList<Integer> and extend all your classes from that wrapper. That way, if you ever have to do exception handling, you can do it in the wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just really can't Compose, and I'm not sure why you can't, I say trust the super class. Especially given that this is a Java API Class that.

- Is well known to all experienced developers
- has a contract is extremely unlikely to change

Duplicate code is almost always the worst option IMO. The only reason I could see to argue for it in a case similar to this is if the class you are extending a poorly implemented Class and you are trying to hide it's problems to the outside world, or if it throws exceptions that you just really don't want to be coupled to.

Comment: Extremely unlikely to change? Look at the Java 8 implementation of ArrayList and compare it with Java 7.

Comment: I'm actually wondering whether the compiler will even run that line of code, `size < 0` - as it should be pretty clear that it's dead code.

Comment: @JB Nizet is ArrayList's contract different or just it's implementation?

Comment: Many new methods are appearing.

Comment: @JB Nizet In this case that does that matter if none of the old ones have changed?

Comment: You can't have any guarantee that old methods aren't implemented by delegating to newer ones, and vice versa. This makes inheritance a very fragile way of reusing code, because you're forced to rely on varying implementation details rather than on a contract. Josh Bloch explains it very well in its Effective Java book. Follow the link I posted in my comment on the question. Collections shouldn't be subclassed. Composition should be favored.

Comment: "Composition should be favored." I agree one million percent, but he says he can't for reasons unknown. I still think extension is better than duplication.